# Vi search range and replace

Tags: regular-expression, vi

I'm using `vi` on a Tru64 system that isn't letting me use the `\1` methods.

So simple question I can't find the answer to:

How do you concatenate a search (for the range) with a substitution? Something that would look like this, but it doesn't work:

```
:/^group/s/\w$/Test/
```

For those interested I was trying to do this with `\1`:

```
:%s/\(group\s\+\)\w/\1Test/
```

Comment: What Unix and `vi` is this?

Comment: It would be helpful with an example. I'm not sure I know what you want with `\w`.

Comment: Alternatively, show how you would do what it is you want to do, but in Vim or Sed.

Comment: `:g/^group/s/\w$/Test/`

Comment: Just for information: Bill Joy's original `vi` was able to use `\1` in replacements. I think it's better to show us what it is you're wanting to do. But I don't see how that's related to the search range in your question.

Comment: @Kusalananda It's Tru64, not sure of vi version, about 20 years old. The '\w' is to denote a "word".

Comment: @JJoao, that doesn't work on my system. It just goes to an instance (seems like the last instance) but does no substitution.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Try `&` instead of `\1`

Comment: @xhienne: right, but he will have to match the replacement text exactly. & is replaced by whatever was matched.

Comment: @xhienne no, got a 'Substitute pattern match failed error', still no go.

Comment: @Nick Since the only thing that is not inside parentheses is a zero-length `\w`, there would no difference between `\1` and `&`... if `&` had the expected behavior. @Lance Roberts Does a mere search with the same pattern `\(group\s\+\)\w` match the expected lines?

Comment: I don't think the OP's search pattern works. @LanceRoberts can you describe exactly what you are trying to match? Best to show a line before and after the desired replacement.

Comment: @xhienne No it didn't. Working that down it looks like it can't even find ':/group\s/'. but it does work with ':/group/' so it looks like my system can't handle '\s'.

Comment: Use `/group[ ]*/` where the brackets enclose a space and a TAB character to match white space.

Comment: I suspect your `vi` neither knows `\w` nor `\s`. Try what happens with `:/^group/s/.$/Test/` and adapt it to fill your requirement (like `[a-zA-Z_]`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issues here are the use of the shorthand notations `\w` and `\s`.  If the editor is the *traditional* implementation of `vi` (Bill Joy's original sources), then one may additionally want to set the `magic` option which is set by default in most modern implementations of `vi`. This is done with `:set magic`.

---

`vi` does not understand `\w` and `\s` and similar shorthand notation for various character classes like `vim` does.

To do your substitution in `vi`, use

```
:%s/^\(group[  ][  ]*\)[0-9A-Za-z_]/\1Test/
```

According to [the `vim` documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/character-classes), `\w` corresponds to `[0-9A-Za-z_]` and `\s` is a space or a tab (there's a space and a tab in both `[  ]` above).

The `E+` pattern, where `E` is some expression,  may be replaced by `EE*`.

The `\1` in the replacement part of the substitution should be working in `vi` (any `vi`).  If it doesn't, try `nvi` ("new `vi`") or see if you are able to install `vim`.

The original `vi` (packaged as `traditional-vi` on at least some BSD systems) need to have its "special characters" (except `^` and `$`) escaped, like `\*` and `\.` etc. Alternatively, you may set the `magic` option with `:set magic` (this is normally the default in modern `vi` implementations).

The above substitution would replace all occurrences of (for example)

```
group 1
```

with

```
group Test
```

Another way of doing the same thing that you tried:

```
:g/^group/s/[0-9A-Za-z_]$/Test/
```

or just

```
:g/^group/s/.$/Test/
```

if you don't need to be too careful with that last character on the line.

If you had wanted to replace the last *word* (not just the last character) on the line:

```
:g/^group/s/[^ ]*$/Test/
```

In traditional `vi` without the `magic` option set, this may have to be written

```
:g/^group/s/\[^ ]\*$/Test/
```

Comment: That worked great, though I had to add an asterik after your word construction to catch the whole word. Thanks.